# Can multiple RetrieveRequest objects be set in a single Retrieve?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm using the PHP library for the ExactTarget API.

I want to pull a subscriber and the subscriber's lists in one API call.  Is it possible?  What are the allowances and limitations of retrieve.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.  The RetrieveRequest in SOAP only supports a single object.  It would need to be two requests, one for the Subscriber object, then another for the ListSubscriber object to find the lists they are on.

Comment: Thank you for answering this.  I imagine that the specifications for forming SOAP envelopes may consider this a bad practice. May I suggest this as a feature in the future of the API? As for latency issues, combining multiple retrieves is very efficient, especially for the applications we are building around ExactTarget's API.  Mainly, we don't want our customers to wait for multiple hops between networks for data.